# When "sure" property is equivalent to "almost sure" property?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space.

We say that some property holds surely if it holds $\forall \omega \in \Omega$

And some property holds almost surely if exists $N \in \mathcal{F}, P(N) = 0$  such that the property holds $\forall \omega \in \Omega \setminus N$.

It is obvious that if the sample space $\Omega$ is uncountable then "sure" property is just a particular case of the appropriate "almost sure" property because it is possible that $N \ne \varnothing$ in the definition above.

**I want to know when "sure" property is equivalent to "almost sure" property.**

I think these properties are equivalent if and only if the following condition holds: $P(E) = 0 \iff E = \varnothing$ where $E \in \mathcal{F}$. In particular, this is true for the "classical model" where $P(\omega) = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}, \, \forall \omega \in \Omega$.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you just need the empty set to be the only set of measure zero. Any finite discrete space should work. I doubt there are any others. Intuitively, once you have an infinite set of outcomes, you will get probability zero. So I think you are correct.

Comment: @jdods  More generally, consider discrete random variables with countably infinite support

Comment: @jdods Let $\Omega = \mathbb{N}_+$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and define $P$ by $P(\{n\}) = 6/n^2 \pi^2$. Then $|\Omega|$ is infinite but $P(E) = 0 \iff E = \varnothing$.

Comment: So in the first comment above we should replace "infinite set" by "uncountable set"

Comment: Yes, my mistake, you can have countably infinite state space. More simply, just let $P(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all probability spaces sure implies almost sure.

For the converse you need that $\mu(A)=0\implies A=\emptyset$.

Really though don't get caught up in "sure" vs "almost sure". I haven't seen a situation where the distinction mattered. (Although I welcome examples).